# Is there a way to strip the end of a string until a certain character is reached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, strip, python-re

I'm working on a side project for myself and have stumbled on an issue that I'm not sure how to solve for. I have a url, for arguments sake let's say https://stackoverflow.com/xyz/abc. I'm attempting to strip the the end of the url so that I am only left with https://stackoverflow.com/xyz/.

Initially I tried to use the strip function and specify a length/position to remove up to, but realized for other url's I'm working with, it is not the same length. (i.e. URL 1 = /xyz/abc, URL 2 = /xyz/abcd))

Is there any advice for achieving this, I looked into using the regular expression operations in Python, but was unsure how to apply it to this use case. Ideally I would like to write a function that would start from the end of the string and strip away all characters till the first '/' is reached. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would use `urllib.parse` with `pathlib` instead of regex.

Comment: `'https://stackoverflow.com/xyz/abc'.rsplit('/', 1)[0]`

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `rfind`, which starts from the end?

```py
>>> string = 'https://stackoverflow.com/xyz/abc'
>>> string = string[:string.rfind('/')+1]
>>> print(string)
'https://stackoverflow.com/xyz/'
```

And if you don't want the character either (the `/` in this case), simply remove the `+1`.

Keep in mind however that this only works if the string actually contains the character you are looking for.
If you want to protect against this, you will have to use the following:

```py
string = 'https://stackoverflow.com/xyz/abc'
idx = string.rfind('/')
if(idx != -1):
    string = string[:idx+1]
```

Unless, obviously, you do want to end up with an empty string in case the character is not found.
Then the first example works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

if yo dont want to use regex, you can combine both the split and join().

```
lol = 'https://stackoverflow.com/xyz/abc'
splt= lol.split('/')[:-1]
'/'.join(splt)
```

output

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/xyz'
```

Comment: appreciate the advice, will look into applying this to see if it works for the entire use case I'm working with